# Strawberry Shake graphql init - use ssl certificate

Tags: .net-core, graphql, strawberryshake

I am just starting out using Strawberry Shake to generate a client for a GraphQL API.

I have run through the Getting Started, but the API I am connecting to requires SSL Cert authentication.

I can successfully connect to the API using Postman and curl but cannot find anything in the documentation for Strawberry Shake to specify cert / passphrase in the `graphql init` command

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% certain that this is the *right* way to do it, but the following worked for me

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyStrawberryShakeClient>(c =>
                {

                }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
                {
                    return new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, certChain, policyErrors) => true
                    };
                });
                services.AddMyStrawberryShakeClient()
                    .ConfigureHttpClient(client =>
                    {
                        ...
                    });
```

As far as I'm aware, this isn't secure however, as it just ignores certificate validation entirely

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work for me as I need to add my client certificate to the connection as its the server I am connecting too that will be validating it

Comment: You would add your validation method to ServerCertificateValidationCallback

Comment: As I said, I am not validating the server cert. The server is validating my client cert. The code you have posted allows a client to ignore a bad server certificate (i.e. out of date)

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood, apologies

Comment: also, my question is specifically about the init command which generates the schema classes, there is no code in use at all at this point :)

Comment: @Shevek Have you found the fix for this? I'm getting a 422 error at this step and I suppose it's due to similar reasons.

Comment: @Hugo nope, unfortunately not. We gave up using Strawberry Shake in the end

Comment: @Shevek What other Tool are you now using ? I am having the same issue in a project im working on.

Comment: @Max we used PostMan's discovery feature to map out their API then https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client to integrate

Comment: @Shevek ouh okay thanks for the fast reply :)